# Bootstrap Collapse With Multiple Embedded Rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, rows

Quick question on bootstrap and columns/rows. I have a cascade effect that has managers, then employees, then employee family members.

The problem is that I do not have a full understanding of bootstrap and how it uses columns/rows.

I get this result when running my code at the bottom [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90oIg.png)

But I need this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miSKl.png)

I know this is not achieveable with my current code... Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @{i++;}
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#@i">Manager Name</button>
            <div id="@i" class="collapse">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <h5>Employees</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        j++;
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#@j">Employee Name</button>
                            <br />
                            <div id="@j" class="collapse">

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <h5>Employee Fam Members</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                         @Html.ActionLink(Employee Fam Member Name, blah, blah)
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                            </div>
                            <br />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">

                        <br />
                        <br />

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1">
            Edit Button    
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-7">
            Delete Button 
        </div>

    </div>
    <br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than putting rows inside of columns, you'll have to make a bunch of rows on the same level instead. Otherwise the new rows would only be the width of the column it was placed in. Also, container-fluid to make it fully full width if you'd like.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#i">Manager Name</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            Edit Button    
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            Delete Button 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="i" class="collapse">
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <h5>Employees</h5>
            </div>
       </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#j">Employee Name</button>
            </div>
       </div>   
    </div>
    <div id="j" class="collapse">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h5>Employee Fam Members</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                 @Html.ActionLink(Employee Fam Member Name, blah, blah)
            </div>
        </div>                                
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank You! But yes container-fluid is a day saver!